# Escape comma (=delimiter) in Doctrine's `simple_array` type

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, symfony4

Is there a way to somehow enter (e.g. escape) a literal `,` (comma) in one of the array values of [Doctrine's `simple_array` data type](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/2.8/reference/types.html#simple-array) ? What I want to get are two array values like this:

- foo,bar
- second entry

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to *escape* the comma, since Doctrine just uses PHP's [`explode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) function at [`Doctrine\DBAL\Types\SimpleArrayType::convertToPHPValue()`](https://github.com/doctrine/dbal/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Types/SimpleArrayType.php#L69). So whatever "wanna-be-escape-character" you enter before the comma will not affect the exploding.

As a workaround, you could come up with some special character(s) as your "internal replacement" for the comma, and convert it back in the Entity's getter:

```
const COMMA_REPLACEMENT = '||'; // be sure to choose something that you'll *never* need in one of the strings

public function getName()
{
    return array_map(function($value)
        {
            return str_replace(self::COMMA_REPLACEMENT, ',', $value);
        },
        $this->name
    );
}
```

I suggested this as a new feature for Doctrine: https://github.com/doctrine/dbal/issues/3300